LinkedIn Image Share from Email
I'm completely unfamiliar with the LinkedIn api, but I am trying to figure out if it's possible to create an Image Share with a pre-populated message and image from an email. User receives an email, in the email is a button that says "Share on linkedIn". Clicking the button authenticates them, then gives them a pop-up with the message, which they can customize, and an image. Is this doable from email, or does it have to be from an app?
